# magento blocks position

Tags: php, css, xml, magento

I want to replace a module with another in magento how can I do this (means I want to put Community Poll module to the left ) is there anything like joomla?

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the layout is defined in the XML files. The best way to go about it is to search the layout folder in App/Design/Frontend/Default/whateverthemeyouareusing for the names of the blocks you want to re-arrange. You'll find there might be more than one call for a block. They will have a position stated in the reference name, either left or right, and can also be before or after another module. Changing these values will move the blocks around.

For example:

```
< reference name="left">
        < block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
< /reference>
```

Comment: And if you need to change some layouts and templates, it is a good idea not to edit the layout in default/default, but instead create your own (default/vipinsahu for instance), copy the files you change in there respecting the folder structure, and configure Magento to use vipinsahu as the default design.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in app/layout/default/default/layout - you should be able to swap a value out in the XML there to cause a different block to be displayed.

I'll try and remember to look in more detail when I've got a dev copy of magento to hand and will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The layout is defined in XML files.

Read [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts) to understand the basic philosophy and [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/40756/) for a crash course in changing the layout.